# Can't replace hex in bytes with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, binaryfiles

```
>>> data=b'\x11\x22'
>>> data.hex()
'1122'
>>> len(data)
2
#let's try to replace data ....
>>> data.replace(b'1122',b'3344').hex()
'1122'
```

Why I can't replace with `replace` 0x1122 to 0x3344 ?

Comment: `data.hex().replace('1122','3344')`

Comment: @dawg I want to  replace binary data , not string data

Comment: `data.hex().replace('1122','3344').encode('ascii')`

Comment: @MicrosoctCprog try:
`data.replace(b'\x11\x22',b'\x33\x44')`

Comment: `data.replace(b'1122',b'3344')` doesn't change anything because `data` *does not contain* `1122`, it contains `b'\x11\x22'` which is something quite different. The bytestring `b'1122'`, if you use hex escapes, is `b'\x31\x31\x32\x32'` and not  `b'\x11\x22'`.

Comment: `b'1122'` *is not in* `b'\x11\x22'`... `bytes` objects don't "contain" hex in any sense, hex is a method of *representing* the bytes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your `bytes` doesn't contain `1122` (four discrete ASCII values representing `'1'`, `'1'`, `'2'`, `'2'`), it contains `\x11\x22` (two discrete raw byte encodings, `0x11`, `0x22`). If you want to replace the raw byte values, provide them for the replacement, e.g.

```
data.replace(b'\x11\x22',b'\x33\x44').hex()
```